# Regex - Not a word in a place in string

Tags: php, regex, string

Is there any regex like this:

"/Hello my name is [ANYTHING THAT IS NOT "john"], and I like pizza/"

So when I match with this regex, it should return true as long as the place where the name is is not "john".

```
"Heloo my name is abcd, and I like pizza" --> false
"Hello my name is asdf, and I like pizza" --> true
"Hello my name is john, and I like pizza" --> false
```

What should my regex look like to do this in the best way?

Comment: why is first one false

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: @vks Because the string is not Hello, it's Heloo with 2 oos

Comment: @xeraphim I have already checked that, it doesn't work for what I want.

Comment: actually it does... try `/Hello my name is ((?!john).)*$/`

Comment: @xeraphim actually it doesn't

Comment: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/8HF please...

Comment: @xeraphim The problem is that that regex don't care what's after john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hello\smy\sname\sis\s(?:(?!\bjohn\b).)*?\sand\sI\slike\spizza
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/14

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
/Hello my name is (?!john)[^,]+, and I like pizza/
```

Comment: Cool, but what does that [^,]+ mean?

Comment: `[^,]+` means one or more characters that isn't a comma.

Comment: @Murplyx - `Cool, but what does that [^,]+ mean?` Its a character class, says not a comma chracter, quantified 1 to many times. You can restrict it so it doesn't  go past a newline by `[^,\n]+`.

Answer (score 0):

The one through PCRE verb [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272200/3297613)

```
Hello my name is john, and I like pizza(*SKIP)(*F)|Hello my name is [^,]+, and I like pizza

|<----String you don't want----------->|<-VERB--->|<------String you want----------------->
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bM4vP1/1)